# How I can get the correct date of my Mysql query without the query itself subtracting one day to date

Tags: mysql, date, intellij-idea, data-conversion

My problem is that in a table of my database with 7 columns, I have a column of date type, called "Fecnac". Through *MYSQLworkbrench*, I execute a simple query:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblAsegurados ORDER BY Name,Nss"
```

As a result of this query, the information of my columns or fields of the table is displayed, the table contains a column named "Fecnac" that shows the correct date, for example "2018-12-31".

[MYSQLworkbrench Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7WYF.png)

However, I developed an application in intelliJ IDEA to execute the same query, and the query "by itself" returns the date with one day less, that is, it shows "2018-12-30". And so it does with all the dates found in the "Fecnac" column of the "tblAsegurados" table in my database.

```
public ArrayList<Asegurados> getAseguradosList(){
    ArrayList<Asegurados> aseguradosList = new ArrayList<Asegurados>();
    Connection connection = getConnection();
    var query = "select * from tblAsegurados order by Nombre,Nss";
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        st = connection.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        Asegurados asegurado;
        while(rs.next()){
            asegurado = new Asegurados(
                    rs.getString("Nss"),
                    rs.getString("Nombre"),
                    rs.getString("Curp"),
                    rs.getBoolean("Esposa"),
                    rs.getInt("Semcot"),
                    rs.getInt("Hijos"),
                    rs.getDate("Fecnac"));
            aseguradosList.add(asegurado);

            System.out.println(asegurado.getFecnac());
            System.out.println(rs.getDate("Fecnac"));
            System.out.println(rs.getDate(7));
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return aseguradosList;
}
```

The class "Asegurados" has an attribute of type "java.sql.date" defined, to receive "rs.getdate (Fecnac).

For i be sure of the values ​​returned by the query, in my code you can see that I made a "System.out.println" for each field date, and in all three I get the same value from the date with one day less.

Could someone help me know what happens?

[Console debug IntelliJ Idea image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaq4v.png)

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution. In a part of my code, the parameter of the time zone had it defined as: *serverTimezone = UTC*

```
public static Connection getMySQLConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/imss"+
            "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true"+
            "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Mexico_City"+
            "&verifyServerCertificate=false"+
            "&useSSL=true"+
            "&requireSSL=true";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "juan1980";
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
```

I set it to: ***serverTimezone = america / Mexico_City***, which is the zone that corresponds to me, and ready! the date is displayed correctly.

Comment: After reading your question I was about to suggest to check the timezones, but you already found it :-) PS. don't forget to accept your own answer. It's not a shame to accept your own answers, in fact you are encouraged to do so!